# Is there something wrong with the following sentence and if there is, how should it be fixed

Tags: phrase-usage

> until today I still remember this incidence

Or should it be *up to this day* ?
Are both Okay is is one preferred?

Comment: Did you mean 'incident'?

Comment: Where did you see this sentence? Was it a native speaker?

Answer (score 1):

If it means what I think it means, it should be
**I still remember this incident.**

*Incident*  means an occurrence in the past.
*Incidence* usually means some other things (check a dictionary).

The phrase *until today* means up until now, but it might suggest that after today, you won't remember it.
*Still remember* doesn't suggest that possibility.